# Python - Writing a log to a file

Tags: python, logging

I currently have logging setup for console.

Im invoking my config using :

```
import logging
import logging.config

logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf')
logger = logging.getLogger('osPatch')
```

My config is ::

```
[loggers]
keys=root,osPatch

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler

[formatters]
keys=osPatch

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler

[logger_osPatch]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler
qualname=osPatch
propagate=0

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=osPatch
args=(sys.stdout,)

[formatter_osPatch]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt=
```

This gives me console level logging perfectly fine.

Now I want the same logs to be written to a file.

What im trying to do is edit my config file and use a [fileHandler](https://docs.python.org/2.3/lib/node304.html).

So Im editing my config file to :

```
[loggers]
keys=root,osPatch

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler,FileHandler

[handler_FileHandler]
filename=example.log
level=DEBUG
formatter=osPatch
```

This gives me an ERROR :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "apply_errata.py", line 1, in <module>
    import satellite_utils
  File "/root/config-3.1.25/automated-os-patching/satellite_utils.py", line 3, in <module>
    import system_utils
  File "/root/config-3.1.25/automated-os-patching/system_utils.py", line 4, in <module>
    import processing_utils
  File "/root/config-3.1.25/automated-os-patching/processing_utils.py", line 7, in <module>
    logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf')
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/logging/config.py", line 85, in fileConfig
    _install_loggers(cp, handlers, disable_existing_loggers)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/logging/config.py", line 253, in _install_loggers
    logger.addHandler(handlers[hand])
KeyError: 'FileHandler'
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: See answer below, if that doesn't help maybe post your full config file instead of the rather vague "I started with this, and edited this here", makes it hard to really know what your actual file looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how your full config file looks, but that traceback in my experience indicate that the handler key isn't properly declared in the handler section.

For reference, this is a tried and working version of the config file I think you aim to create:

```
[loggers]
keys=root,osPatch

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler,FileHandler

[formatters]
keys=osPatch

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler,FileHandler

[logger_osPatch]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler,FileHandler
qualname=osPatch
propagate=0

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=osPatch
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_FileHandler]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=osPatch
args=('example.log',)

[formatter_osPatch]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt=
```